# Stokes' theorem exercise

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

Find the work performed by the force field 
$${\bf F}(x, y, z) = x^2 {\bf \vec i} + 4xy^3 {\bf \vec j} + y^2 x{\bf \vec k}$$ 
on a particle that traverses the contour $C$; where $C$ is the boundary of the rectangular part of the plane $z = y$ above the rectangle $R=\{0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq 3\}$.

I have got to the point where $\nabla\times F = 2xy {\bf \vec i} - y^2 {\bf \vec j} + 4y^3 {\bf \vec k}$
and $n = {\bf \vec j} - {\bf \vec k}$

$$\iint (\nabla\times F) \cdot {\bf n} \;dS = -90$$

the second side of the solution I wasn't able to do.

Comment: And why haven't you shown us your work?

Comment: I've got so messy with it that's why I'm asking if anyone knows the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just evaluate
$$\iint_R \text{curl}({\bf F})\cdot {\bf n}\; dydx
=-\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^3 (y^2+4y^3)\; dydx=-\left[\frac{y^3}{3}+y^4\right]_{0}^3=-(9+81)=-90.$$
The same result can be obtained directly by evaluating
$$\int_{\partial R} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}=\sum_{i=1}^4\int_{\gamma_i} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}=0+\frac{1}{3}-90-\frac{1}{3}=-90$$
where the are four sides are:

$\gamma_1(t)=(0,t,t)$ for $t\in [0,3]$;

$\gamma_2(t)=(t,3,3)$ for $t\in [0,1]$;

$\gamma_3(t)=(1,3-t,3-t)$ for $t\in [0,3]$;

$\gamma_4(t)=(1-t,0,0)$ for $t\in [0,1]$.

Comment: I did that how about the $\int_c\; F.dr$ ? 
actually it's there where i got lost.
any help please?

Comment: @Basel Mazaz It is equal by Stokes 'theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem)

Comment: I am supposed to prove that it is equal so how can i prove it. I know I need to use the polar coordinate as a start but i can't follow after that. Is it possible that you show me how?

Comment: @Basel Mazaz I see. Read my edited answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I will work more on it till I get right, Thank you